# Authorization of clients (VS Code, Data Loader)

Tags: integration, oauth2, visualstudiocode

To use the OAuth protocol, you need to create a connected app on Salesforce. Through consumer key and secret key it is possible to implement different oAuth flows. But how does it work with Visual Studio code or Data Loader? I don't have any connected apps! which consumer key and secret key are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can login to an org without oAuth via SOAP [login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) operation with username/password as your credentials. Data Loader uses SOAP login if you choose the `Password Authentication` option. (It also supports oAuth).

VS Code authorizes via sfdx underneath the hood. The latter goes against a ["global" connected app](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth.htm) that resides in Dev Hub (used by all orgs):

> The Dev Hub org allows you to create, delete, and manage your
>   Salesforce scratch orgs. After you set up your project on your local
>   machine, you authorize with the Dev Hub org before you can create a
>   scratch org.
>
> You have some options when configuring authentication depending on
>   what you’re trying to accomplish.
>
> We provide the OAuth Refresh Token flow, also called web-based flow,
>   through a global out-of-the-box connected app. When you authorize an
>   org from the command line, you enter your credentials and authorize
>   the global connected app through the Salesforce web browser
>   authentication flow.